# メンテナンス等でスタック・オーバーフローが使えない時間の確認方法について

Tags: サポート

スタック・オーバーフローをよく覗いているのですが、
メンテナンス等で使えないときがあります。

完全に使えなくなる少し前くらいに
タイトルの上のあたりに案内が表示されるのですが、
その時になって初めて使えなくなることに気が付きます。

ところで、スタック・オーバーフローが使えない時間を
簡単に知る方法（例えば、どこかに案内されている等）
を教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

英語のみになりますが、Twitterで書いてあります：

https://twitter.com/stackstatus

基本的にダウンタイムを計画しません。たまにCDNの問題、バックアップサーバーへの移動時間等がありますので、上記のTwitterで最新情報が公開しています。